# How in CDMA mobiles receiver gets unique code to decode its respective signal?

Tags: communication, mobile, receiver

Transmitted data in CDMA mobile is encoded with a random code. Receiver requires this random code to decode data from the received signal.

From where the receiver will get this random code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is statistically random but it is not secret.  In fact, it's chosen to not conflict with another code on the same frequency.  Both ends know the code--it's part of the notion of "channel number".  This code sequence stuff is common and you will find the same thing in GPS, and even modems.  Sometimes it is called "scrambling".

Comment: transmitter will insert a code right? same code should be known to receiver only then it can decode right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then from where exactly receiver will get this code? (in my knowledge it is only known to transmitter)

Comment: It is known to both. Both have microprocessors, and the code is part of their program.

Comment: sorry if am thinking in the wrong direction. That means each receiver will be having unique code and this code is related to phone number.

Comment: There are several possible codes, and the receiver knows all of them.  The base station will tell the mobile which of the codes is to be used.  That's the analog equivalent of telling it which channel to switch to.

Answer (score 0):

The unique code is not truly random, it is a psuedorandom bit sequence generated by a linear-feedback shift register (LFSR) or something similar. The method of generating the code is predetermined and known to both the transmitter and the receiver.

Comment: for mobile communication is it possible to predetermine method of generating code between each mobile?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'm answering in the general case because your question does not clearly pertain to a particular communication system. For example, the phrase "each mobile" is pretty vague.

Comment: as you said I edited my question. My doubt is actually related to mobile communication.

Comment: The phrase "mobile communication" just means communication between objects that move. My answer pertained to objects that move, such as a GPS satellite and a GPS receiver.

Comment: Presumably the answer for mobile phones is buried in the CDMA2000 spec somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking specifically about CDMA as used in the cellular telephone system. [This tutorial](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/cdma/cdmatutorial5.html) offers some hints.

Basically, the signal-spreading codes are pre-assigned based on the carrier frequency and the logical channel being used on that frequency. Any particular mobile device gets a frequency/channel assignment by monitoring a control channel that is broadcast by the base station.

Comment: transmitted data is encoded with a random code. Receiver requires this random code to decode transmitted data. My doubt is from where receiver will get this random code.

Comment: The pseudo-random code sequence is agreed in advance and programmed in to cellular equipment.  Don't forget that both cell phones and cell towers are transmitters & receivers.